# How do I transform an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, transform

I have an array of the form:

```
[

    {
        foo:{
            name: 'One',
            value: 10
        },
        bar: {
            name: 'Two',
            value: 20
        }
    }

]
```

I want to get an array of the form:

```
[
    {
        name: 'One',
        value: 10
    },
    {
        name: 'Two',
        value: 20
    }
]
```

Can I transform it with a map, for example?
Or do I need another way?

Comment: `Object.entries`

Comment: The first code block is not a valid JavaScript. If it's an object literal and not in array look into [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) or [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)

Comment: Does the first array always contain exactly one element?

Comment: @ArtyomNeustroev I'm sorry - I originally specified the wrong kind of array. Corrected

Comment: @jabaa - no, not always

Comment: What's the expected result of `[{ foo: {}, bar: {} }, { bar: {} }]`?

Comment: @jabaa ```[{},{},{}...]```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) along with [Array.flatMap()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)to get the required result:

```js
let arr = [
    {
        foo:{
            name: 'One',
            value: 10
        },
        bar: {
            name: 'Two',
            value: 20
        }
    }
]


let result = arr.flatMap(obj => Object.values(obj));
console.log('Result:', result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I'm sorry - I originally specified the wrong kind of array. Corrected

Comment: I've updated my answer now, thanks!

Comment: `Object.values` can be used also like this `arr.flatMap(Object.values)`

Answer (score 1):

flatMap function is not supported by all versions, you can [check this](https://jsfiddle.net/yw7mznfs/2/)

you can try this function with supported array methods example:

```
function transform(arr) {
   let empty = [];
   arr.forEach(obj => {
       const secondArr = Object.entries(obj);
       empty.push(...secondArr.map(arr => arr[1]));
   });
return empty;
}
```

here is an example in [JSFiddle PlayGround](https://jsfiddle.net/yw7mznfs/1/)

Comment: @jabaa it was a mistake sorry, i replaced it by forEach

Comment: @jabaa the return statment is for the function "transform" not for method forEach

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT: I saw that you corrected the original post, and this answer is not relevant anymore, because the array I guess you wanted to define is not what you actually wanted to. I'll leave my original answer for educational purposes, but to answer your question I would recommend to check @terry-lennox answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/70770819/12166040**

---

The first array you specified is invalid: it would mean both elements have this shape:

```
foo: {
    name: 'One',
    value: 10
}
```

That's not a valid element. I guess you meant to every element be an object itself, like:

```
{
    foo: {
        name: 'One',
        value: 10
    }
}
```

So, the original array should be:

```
[{
    foo: {
        name: 'One',
        value: 10
    }
}, {
    bar: {
        name: 'Two',
        value: 20
    }
}]
```

Having this, your goal is to **retrieve the object of the first key in every element of the array**. You can do it this way:

```
yourArray.map(item => item[Object.keys(item)[0]]);
```

`map()` will return a new array by running its function parameter for every element of `yourArray`. And the function specified inside `map()` just returns whatever is inside on the first key of every item.

Answer (score 1):

As map function will return results in the form of nested arrays. We are only interested in the value part of the object present in the object. So we can use Objects.values() to get that. In the end, we can flatten the nested array to obtain the required result

```js
let data = [

  {
    foo: {
      name: 'One',
      value: 10
    },
    bar: {
      name: 'Two',
      value: 20
    }
  }

];

console.log(
  Object.values(data).map(i => {
    return Object.values(i);
  }).flat()
);
```

Comment: Please explain why they can use this?

Comment: As map function will return results in the form of nested arrays. We are only interested in the value part of the object present in the object. So we can use Objects. values to get that. In the end, we can flatten the nested array to obtain the required result

Comment: (Sorry I meant, may you edit the answer)